# Updating p in div with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to update the text of a `p` element which has a `.bus_latitude` class.

So first, I locate the parent div which has a `data-* attribute`.
After retrieving the div, I try to locate his closest p element which has the class `.bus_latitude`, and set his text to some static content.
I have tried enoumerous ways, specially because jQuery has various methods to do so, but none of them worked.

So here I inject a div with has a `data-id` attr
this:

```html
var div = $('<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 bus_card" data-id="'+bus.getKey()+'"><br/><br/>'+
  '<div class="thumbnail">'+
  '  <div class="caption">'+
  '    <div class="col-lg-12">'+
  '      <div class="header">'+
  '       <h4 class = "line_name" style="text-align:center;color:'+line.child("colorNormal").val()+';"><strong>Linha '+line.getKey()+'</strong></h4>'+
  '      </div>'+
  '    </div>'+
  '    <div class="col-lg-12 well well-add-card">'+
  '      <h4 class="pull-left">Cartão:</h4>'+
  '      <h4 class="pull-right">'+bus.child('cardid').val()+'</h4>'+
  '    </div>'+
  '    <div class="col-lg-12 bus_information">'+
  '      <div style="padding-left:10px!important;" class="row">'+
  '        <p class="pull-left"><kbd>Latitude</kbd></p>'+
  '        <p class="pull-right bus_latitude">'+bus.child('lat').val()+'</p>'+
  '      </div>'+
  '      <div style="padding-left:10px!important;" class="row">'+
  '        <p class="pull-left"><kbd>Longitude</kbd></p>'+
  '        <p class="pull-right bus_longitude">'+bus.child('long').val()+'</p>'+
  '      </div>'+
  '      <div style="padding-left:10px!important;" class="row">'+
  '        <p class="pull-left"><kbd>Velocidade:</kbd></p>'+
  '        <p class="pull-right bus_velocity">35km/h</p>'+
  '      </div>'+
  '      <div style="padding-left:10px!important;white-space: nowrap; overflow:hidden;" class="row">'+
  '        <p class="pull-left"><kbd>Geo-localização:</kbd></p>'+
  '        <class = "bus_georeference">&nbsp&nbsp'+streetNameOfPosition+'</>'+
  '      </div>'+
  '    </div>'+
  '    <button type="button" class="btn '+(bus.child('state').val() === 1 ? 'btn-danger' : 'btn-default')+' btn-xs btn-update btn-add-card">Em Terminal</button>'+
  '    <button type="button" class="btn '+(bus.child('state').val() === 2 ? 'btn-danger' : 'btn-default')+' btn-xs btn-update btn-add-card">Em Andamento</button>'+
  '    <button type="button" class="btn '+(bus.child('state').val() === 3 ? 'btn-danger' : 'btn-default')+' btn-xs btn-update btn-add-card">Em Paragem</button>'+
  '  </div>'+
  '</div>'+
'</div>').appendTo("#bus-cards-container");
```

So I have an event listener for a button to update the p element with some static content.

Here is where it isn't working:

```
    function updateBusOnHTML(bus) {
       alert(bus.getKey());
       $("div[data-id='" + bus.getKey() +"'] .bus_information .bus_latitude").val("39.284035"); //this doesn't work, bus.getKey()
}
```

Both data-id are correct, even when the HTML is rendered, the div has the exact same id with the one that enters updateBusOnHTML().
So why doesn't it update the `p` text?

Answer (score 1):

`.val()` is used to update the value of a form element like `input`. Use a method like `.text()` or `.html()` instead.

Another recommendation: use `console.log()` instead of `alert()`.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Yea, I use plenty of console.log to print other type of stuff, I'm using that alert for another purpose, which I forgot to remove.